# Transparent text and image with non-transparent shadow in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, drop-shadow

I have a logo picture and a text in a svg file. Both of them are black. I want to make an image where the original image and text are transparent, but their drop-shadow is visible. How can I do that?

Something like this image (the white area should be transparent, only the shadow is visible).

Moreover, I want to use the drop-shadow function of Inkscape, not a duplication/offset method (because I need blurred shadow).
[image]

Comment: Maybe a sample image could improve your question. A transparent object normally has no shadow. And completely transparent objects aren't visible, so it is pretty unclear, how your image should look like - maybe just a circle and 'foo'-Text as example.

Comment: Much different question than before...

Comment: The same, with some clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily done in Inkscape

1. Create some text. Convert to outlines using `Path` > `Object to Path`, click `Object` > `Ungroup`, then `Path` > `Break Apart`, then turn into a compound path using `Path` > `Combine`.
2. Duplicate the text, so you have a copy.
3. Fill one copy of the text grey.
4. Bring the black copy to the top using `Object` > `Raise to Top`. Move it to partially overlap the black text over the grey.
5. Select both black and grey objects, and click `Path` > `Difference`.
6. Position the graphic over a filled shape to see the transparency.

[image]

Export the resulting graphic as a PNG.

[image: Example PNG]

Comment: It is OK, but it is an "offset solution", it doesn't use the built-in drop-shadow function. Although, it can be good for me, if the shadow can be blurred. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Sorry, can't be done with a blurry shadow as far as I know. GIMP would be better I think - just use a layer mask to knock out the shadow layer.

Comment: @ZsG I take that back.  It is possible if you make a reversed out clipping mask, and apply it to a blurred image of the text like this. http://imgur.com/a/lfjeh - here's the SVG if you want to examine it. http://www.filedropper.com/test_180

Comment: @ZsG: You shouldn't verbally thank, but mark useful answers with an upvote. If there are multiple helpful answers, you should choose one of them as your favorite. If an even better answer appears later, you can change your mind about the best answer.

Comment: I did, but my vote is not visible, because of my low reputation.

Answer (score 0):

A transparent shape can't cover anything.

What you can do, is subtract a copy of a shape from itself. 
You start by a path, so make your text and logo (only works if they are of the same color or will force them to be of same color) a combined path. (Transform text to path, combine text-path and logo-path - Ctrl-K in the german GUI).

- duplicate them (ctrl d)
- move the duplicate a little to the side and up
- mark in addition to the copy (shift click) the original path
- build the difference with (ctrl -). The upper object in Z-axis will always be subtracted from the lower one.

For finer navigation, you might change the color of the duplicate. For even finer positioning, making it semi transparent might help.

[image: Shape and logo]

Here I duplicated shape and text (black), made the duplicate the same color as the bg (white) and moved that to a little offset (sample left).

Font and shape are of the same color (black), so they can be combined to one path. Duplicating the path, moving it in the same way with a little offset but then making the difference between black and white shape (sample right).

The red rectangle in the background is there, to make the difference visible.

Comment: I tried, but the text and its shadow are disappeared. Also, why need duplication?

Comment: Now I understand, but it doesn't work. It were good if the transparent layer would cover (ie. erases) the "shadow layer", but does not.

Comment: An object, which covers or erases the shadow layer, can't be transparent. On the other hand, a transparent thing wouldn't produce a shadow either. :) So if you have a black path on a white bg, you can duplicate it. If you make the duplicate white and place it above the black object with some offset, you might get your desired result. As a 2nd step, you might subtract one path from the other, which would look the same in b/w only, but different, if you move that combination in front of some bg. Combining logo and text to a single path is possible, when of same color.

Comment: I understand the whole thing, except the essence: how can you make the white to transparent (2. image)?

Comment: @ZsG: I updated my answer.